# Create childviews for viewflipper programmatically

Tags: android, view, viewflipper

I've tried making a viewflipper work using an xml as a container of all child views of a viewflipper just like this.

```
<ViewFlipper
android:layout_margin="6dip"
android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#00ff00"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="A dog limps into a saloon and says...">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#00ff00"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="I'm looking for the man who shot my paw!">
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Now, I need to create those child views onCreate of the Game. I'm trying to create a 100x100 map that will only display 5x5 on the screen. This 100 x 100 contains images that will be displayed only 5x5 via viewflipper and when the user slides the screen another 5x5 set of images will be displayed. So with this I need to make a dynamic view flipper. Any ideas? Also, I'm planning to do this animation via accelerometer. Any ideas?